# Basic Encryption Script outputting not valid ASCII text

Tags: c, encryption, cs50, substitution

I'm currently trying to code a basic substitution/encryption script in C for CS50x, and everything is working as I want it to, except after it prints the encrypted text, it prints 1-2 random characters, and I can't seem to figure out why.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

```c
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    //Error print when too many command-line arguments, or invalid string length
    string key = argv[1];
    int keylength = strlen(key);
    int alpha;
    int i = 0;
    if (argv[2] != (void *)0)
    {
        printf("Usage ./substitution (key)\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    if(keylength != 26)
    {
        printf("Key must contain 26 characters.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    do
    {
        alpha = isalpha(argv[1][i]);
        i++;
    }
    while (alpha != 0 && i != 25);
    if(alpha != 0)
    {
        //Fetch plaintext
        string plain = get_string("Plaintext: ");
        int plainlen = strlen(plain);
        char cipher[plainlen];
        char keylower[keylength];
        char keyupper[keylength];
        //Convert plaintext to ciphertext
        for(int k = 0; k < plainlen; k++)
        {
            if(isalpha(plain[k]) != 0)
            {
                if(islower(plain[k]))
                {
                    int y = plain[k] - 97;
                    keylower[y] = tolower(key[y]);
                    cipher[k] = keylower[y];
                }
                else
                {
                    int y = plain[k] - 65;
                    keyupper[y] = toupper(key[y]);
                    cipher[k] = keyupper[y];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                cipher[k] = plain[k];
            }
        }
        //Print ciphertext
        printf("Ciphertext: %s\n", cipher);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Key must contain only alphabetical characters.\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I have tried editing the length of the arrays and just generally editing some of the lines which seemed like they could be conflicting, but to no avail.

Comment: You have not NUL-terminated your string. You did not even allocate enough bytes to do so. As an aside, _please_ use character literals instead of hard-coding magic ASCII constants. I'm talking about 97 and 65, which should be written `'a'` and `'A'`

Comment: OT: Attempting to take the length of a possibly NULL pointer (missing argv[1]) and then trying to cleverly test argv[2] as being NULL is wrong. Why not use argc? It's available and that is its reason for being passed to main()... Further: after a 'return', there's no need for 'else'. Control has gone elsewhere already... Finally, 'strlen()' doesn't give 'cipher[]' enough storage space for the terminating '\0' (that the code currently does NOT append to make 'cipher' a C string... Start with these tips...

Comment: @Fe2O3 There is nothing wrong with testing `argv` for a NULL pointer as the last element. It's perfectly fine to do: `i = 0; while(argv[i] != NULL) {puts(argv[i]; ++i;}` In other words... you don't always need `argc` (but it's wrong that `argv[1]` wasn't tested for NULL)

Comment: Hey, thank you guys for the advice, how exactly would I NUL-terminate the string? I'm still very new to coding of course, so I'm not familiar with the concept.

Comment: @tp23 You terminate a string by adding the NUL character just after the last "normal" character. For instance: `char str[10]; str[0] = 'a'; str[1] = 'b'; str[2] = 'c'; str[3] = '\0'; ` will give you the string "abc" If you don't do `str[3] = '\0';` it is not a legal string due to lack of the termination character

Comment: @SupportUkraine Yes. One can even use `while( *++argv ) func( *argv );`... Don't tell me; tell the OP. Far more conventional, in this case, would be `if( argc != 2 )`, written **ahead** of the call to `strlen( argv[1] );`... Thank you for the _teaching moment_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest fix would be to declare `k` outside the loop then use it to terminate the cipher string:

```
    int k;
    for(k = 0; k < plainlen; k++) {
       // ...
    }
    cipher[k] = '\0';
```